# How to access Object Element inside an Array without a foreach loop

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to learn the use of the Zend Framework and I am facing now the following issue.
I am reading some information from the database for a specific Post. I use Datamapper and Models.

```
$postMapper = new Application_Model_PostMapper();
$post = new Application_Model_Post();
$details = $postMapper->find($postID, $post);
$this->view->postDetail = $details;
```

In my View, I use a foreach($this->postDetail as $value) to read all the Post Information. But I was wondering now, if I can also access an Information without the foreach. I need just the Email Adress in the Controller and can't see why I would need a foreach. But how would I access this? A Zend_Debug comes with the following results:

```
array(1) {
[0] => object(Application_Model_Post)#87 (27) {
["_email":protected] => string(10) "test@testmail.com"
```

It does sound like a very stupid question, but I just don't find a way to read out the Email Adress inside the Controller. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

In your Application_Model_Post class, you would create an accessor method in order to get the private value.

So create a method like this.

```
public function getEmail(){
    return $this->_email;
}
```

To be honest, I think you will already have these methods if you are using a datamapper correctly.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have got Get and Set Methods in my Model already. I use it in my Datamapper. I than return the Information from the Datamapper to the Controller and than from there to the View. In the View I read it out with a Foreach loop. All I am trying to do now is to get the Email Adress out inside the Controller. When I use   `foreach ($details as $value)
  {
   echo $value->postEmail;
  } `in my Controller, it works, but do I really need the foreach? Is there no way to access the Element without it?

Comment: $postMapper returns a model right. So just use $details->getEmail(). I would of thought that was the obvious bit.

Comment: No, if I use `$details->getEmail()` I get the following Error Message `call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object`, but I just found out, that it works if I use `$post->getEmail()` Does this makes sense? I mean all the information is already read out and saved in $details, but now I don't seem to use that...

Comment: Luka I would need to see your data mapper class, and see what the find() method returns to be able to make any judgment on that question.

Comment: Hi, I still have not found any solution for my Problem, yes, I got the Method getEmail() in my Model and I use all the get Methods in my Datamapper to assign everything and return it. If you scroll to my first question, you see what is the output in the controller. I really can not get my head around it. Anyone any other idea?

Comment: I have found the problem, I am such an idiot. In my find Method I returned an Array, that was the reason, why I had to run through a foreach, which of course makes no sense, when I return just 1 Post. When I changed it, I was than able to just write echo $details->postTitle; and it works. Thank you very much for all your feedback. The answers helped me a lot, since I knew than that it should work and it could have been only an Error in the Datamapper which it was. Thanks so much again. What a great and helpfull community here !

Answer (score 0):

When you get data from Model/db by fetchAll, eg:

```
$result = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

you can

```
$result->toArray();

//access like array
$result[0]->some_col_1;
$result[0]->some_col_2;

$result[1]->some_col_1;
$result[1]->some_col_2;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

one of these should work:

- if $details returns an array:  `$email = $details['email']; or =$details[0]['email'];`
- if $details returns an object:  `$email = $details->email;`